# Javasccript (D3) - date comparison returns NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 and trying to compare dates in an array. I want to get the minimum and maximum of it.

The following is my data set.

```
var data = [{ "date": "2016.07.19", "close": 185697.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.20", "close": 185697.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.21", "close": 186601.1 }, { "date": "2016.07.22", "close": 187273.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.25", "close": 186807.74 }];
```

The following is the code segment I am having the issue with

```
   max_x = 0, max_y = 0, min = 100;


  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      max_y = Math.max(max_y, data[i].close);
      max_x = Math.max(max_x, data[i].date);
      min = Math.min(min, data[i].date);
  }
```

When I printed the "min" variable, it printed "NaN".

This is affecting the rest of my code.

Can someone point out where I've gone wrong ?
Is there any other way to do date comparison ?

Comment: You are setting the properties `date` and `close` and call for the properties `number` and `class`?

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake. I edited the code. Now you can see the code with which I tested.

Comment: `date` is a string and not a number

Comment: min=100 but `date` is string. how can you use Math.min()?? Tell us what you actually want to do??

Comment: I have written the following code https://jsfiddle.net/wwod431g/ and want it to have a tooltip like in the following    https://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/unyd6q29/2/. In my code, tooltip is not visible, and at the same time there is one extra line at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date` values are strings. You have to parse them:

```
var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y.%m.%d");
```

After that, you can retrieve the minimum with `d3.min`, the maximum with `d3.max` or both of them with `d3.extent`.

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{ "date": "2016.07.19", "close": 185697.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.20", "close": 185697.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.21", "close": 186601.1 }, { "date": "2016.07.22", "close": 187273.89 }, { "date": "2016.07.25", "close": 186807.74 }];

var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y.%m.%d");

var extent = d3.extent(data.map(function(d){ return parse(d.date)}))

console.log("Minimum: " + extent[0])
console.log("Maximum: " + extent[1])
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: PS: I'm answering only the question stated in the title and in the first paragraph (*"I am using d3 and trying to compare dates in an array. I want to get the minimum and maximum of it."*). I have no idea of what you want to do in your snippet. Please, ask only 1 problem per question, and keep it specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the properties date and close into two arrays separately,such as dateArr ["2016.07.19","2016.07.20","2016.07.21"],closeArr [185697.89,186601.1,187273.89], and sort them by asc,the first item in array is the minimum,and the last item is the maximum.